# Data Transformation task in SSIS taking too much time

Tags: ssis, oracle11g

I have an `SSIS` job which has an `execute sql task.`

In between **OLEDB source and OLEDB destination** , there is a **data conversion** task to *convert non unicode columns to unicode columns.*

I am getting **40,000  rows appox from source with 27 columns** . Out of which, *10 columns undergoes data conversion*.

**The problem here is, it is taking almost 3 hrs to complete this data flow task.**

```
For a record count of 40,000, i think this is too much.

Or will it take that  time to convert ?
```

**When i tried exporting data from OLEDB to flat file, all the records were processed in less than 10 mins.**

So, there is **no problem with the query in OLEDB source**. `It is the data conversion transformation which is taking too much of time.`

Please help me on this.

Comment: try this:
a) export the data from OLEDB to flat file (look like you already done this, this helps identify if the problem is from the connection).
b) read from flat file, perform transformations and save in flat file (this helps identify if the problem is on the transformation).
c) from the last flat file save to the final destination and mesure the timings again.

Comment: Cross post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66436/how-to-fix-type-conversion-error-in-data-flow-task

Comment: Are you writing to Oracle using OLEDB?

Comment: It seems obvious from your test results that the issue is nothing to do with the data conversion task - it is with the component you replaced - the OLE DB Destination.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are using the fast load option in the OLEDB Destination.
[image]

Comment: Also check the Table lock option and set Rows per batch = 100000 and Max insert = 100000.